# how to bring data from php1 to php2

Tags: php, html

i want to ask that how to bring data from 1 php to another php?

for example:
i want to bring $myID from login.php to main_project.php?
following was my coding parts:

**login.php**

```
include("config.php");

$myID = ($_POST['userID']);
$mypassword = ($_POST['password']); 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM staff WHERE sID = '$myID' AND sPw='$mypassword'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$count= mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($count==1)
{
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
    echo "alert('Login sucessfull!');";
    echo "window.location.href='html%20page/main.html';";
    echo "exit;</script>";
}
else
{
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
    echo "alert('Faill!');";
    echo "window.location.href='html%20page/login.html';";
    echo "</script>";
}
```

**main_project.php**

```
<?php 
$sql= "SELECT sType FROM staff WHERE sID = '$myID'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if($result=='admin'){
    $sql="SELECT * FROM project";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
}
else{
    $sql="SELECT * FROM project WHERE pStaff='$myID' ";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
} 
$count= mysqli_num_rows($result);
?>

<table border="2" style= "margin: 0 auto;" >
    <tr>
      <th>No.</th>
      <th>Project Name</th>
      <th>Date</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        echo
        "<tr>
          <td>{$count}</td>
          <td>{$row['pName']}</td>
          <td>{$row['pCreationDate']}</td>
        </tr>";
      }
    ?>
</table>
```

i found out that i have an error on line 9 in main_project.html and i have no idea to solve it?
please help. thanks

Comment: main_project.html??? if you put .html instead of .php how it will work? :)

Comment: @AniruddhaChakraborty oh, i do not know about that! im new to php. im confused that the coding which combine with html and php should save in what form.

Comment: added an answer , please check it , there is also a link how php works! :)

Answer (score 2):

First of all you cannot use php code in .html file you have to save it with .php extension.
To send data from one page to another in php you have to use session
[you could get further information about session using this link.](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp)

Comment: i had change to php file. but still having error. the error was like this "Call to a member function query() on a non-object" on line9.

Comment: There could be a problem in your '$conn' object.. please make sure you entered correct connection credentials in your config file

Answer (score 0):

you should use `main_project.php` instead of `main_project.html`

PHP will execute you use .php in your file

[This](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-php-works.html) is how php works

Comment: i had change to php file. but still having error. the error was like this "Call to a member function query() on a non-object" on line9.

Comment: Where is the $conn instance ?

Comment: i not sure about that because i copy from others. how should i change it?
oyah.. do i need to include(login.php) in main_project.php ?

Comment: just tried. it will alert fail login message and jump to unknown page. it does not process to main_project.

Comment: You can not just copy codes , and fix it , you have to understand the whole thing :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all check the file extensions any file having .html extension will not run any php code. Then go to your phpmyadmin if using and check whether the database you are trying to access exists. If not than create and same for the table you are trying to access.

**Check your connection in config.php** and check whether you are connected to database.If your connection is ok. Then there must be problem with your **query**.Check **main_project.php line no. 2**. Your query is not right because you don't have variable `$myid` on this page. Your query is getting failed so
follow along.

Do this start session on both of your pages like this..

```
include("config.php");

session_start();//session has been started to your page

$myID = ($_POST['userID']);

$mypassword = ($_POST['password']);
```

After the session has started to your page now you can store 
`$myid` variable into super global variable `$_SESSION[index]`. `$_SESSION[]` is a super global variable and you can access it on multiple pages by starting session on each of the page. Do this:

```
    include("config.php");
    session_start();//session has been started to your page 
    $myID = ($_POST['userID']);
    $mypassword = ($_POST['password']); 
     $_SESSION['myid'] = $myid; /* your variable is now a superglobal 
    variable you can access it on main_project.php
```

After you have stored the session data in super global array start session on **main_project.php** just by writing **session_start();** just after the php starting tag.

```
  <?php 
    session_start();
    $sql= "SELECT sType FROM staff WHERE sID = '$_SESSION[myid]'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
```